# How do I get a sound played at startup on XFCE4?

Tags: sound, startup, music

My goal is to play a welcome melody each time I log in into the graphical environment (xfce4). I think I can realize it with the sessions-and-startup program and a short script, which starts  vlc from the command line.

However, I am not able to start VLC without its GUI. 
I read here here some answers to this problem, but they did not work, 
for instance: `vlc -I null` does not work and `vlc --intf dummy` does not work either.

My VLC version is 2.2.2

Comment: why would you want to do this with VLC? why restrict yourself? Use "aplay". It is the tool to use for commandline audio.

Comment: I was not aware that I restrict myself by using VLC, thought it is the standard way of doing it, do not know aplay

Comment: type "aplay" in command line and see the myriad of options ;)

Comment: I ve used aplay,  but it sounded very weird as if a spider humanoid was about to make love  to me, this error message showed up:Playing raw data 'untitled.mp4' : Unsigned 8 bit, Rate 8000 Hz, Mono
^CAborted by signal Interrupt...
aplay: pcm_write:1940: write error: Interrupted system call

Comment: I've edited your title. You've falled into [xy problem trap](http://xyproblem.info). Just ask for your original instead of asking you thought is a _solution_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
cvlc music.mp3
```

`cvlc` is the command-line interface of VLC media player

[image]

Comment: seems  to me to work the  same as vlc music.mp3, what is different?

Comment: i am sure you are right, i must have some bug